# get next and previous rows of a given id with ormlite and android

Tags: java, android, ormlite, query-builder

I want to get next and previous rows of a given id with ormlite and android
the ids in the table is not auto incremented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:
Get all rows:

```
List<MyDataObject> list = myDao.queryForAll();
```

Search the index of your object in the list:

```
int myIndex;
for (MyDataObject obj: list) {
    if (obj.getId().equals("Myid")) {
        myIndex = list.indexOf(obj)
    }
}
```

Get your wanted items:

```
MyDataObject previousObject = list.get(myIndex+1);
MyDataObject nextObject = list.get(myIndex-1);
```

This is one approach. Another way is get only a list of your ids and then search your wanted ids (next and  previous ids) and finally make a query by id.

Comment: Thanks, it works but is there another way using query builder?

Comment: I was searching but I didn't found some solution with query builder.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get next and previous rows of a given id with ormlite and android the ids in the table is not auto incremented

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question but you can certainly select for items that are greater-than your id, ordered by the id, and limit 1.  That would give the next (greater) row.  Using less-than would give the previous row.

Something like:

```
QueryBuilder<Foo> qb = fooDao.queryBuilder();
// we want the items greater than this id
qb.where().gt("id", id); // use lt for previous
// we only want the first one
qb.limit(1);
// order by the id
qb.orderBy("id");
Foo previousFoo = qb.queryForFirst();
```

Hope this helps.